# What is the second part of the address returned by recvfrom?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp

I'm using those 2 pieces of code from http://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication

The server:

```
import socket

UDP_IP="127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT=5005

sock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                      socket.SOCK_DGRAM ) # UDP
sock.bind( (UDP_IP,UDP_PORT) )

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom( 1024 ) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    print "received message:", data,"from", addr
```

The client:

```
import socket

UDP_IP="127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT=5005
MESSAGE="Hello, World!"

print "UDP target IP:", UDP_IP
print "UDP target port:", UDP_PORT
print "message:", MESSAGE

sock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                      socket.SOCK_DGRAM ) # UDP
sock.sendto( MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT) )
```

In the server, I modified the last line:

```
        print "received message:", data,"from", addr
```

so it prints the address that the message was sent from.
On my macbook the port seems to be some random number between 40000 or 65000 (i'm just sure it seems random).

Any idea what this could be ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an [ephemeral port](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Ephemeral_port) used by the client to send data to the server.

Comment: I dont' really understand the utility of this kind of port, is this port here so one application has a change to make some kind of answer ?

Comment: The idea is that the lower number ports are needed for important things that have to listen to them for a long time, so instead of getting in their way, client applications send from any high-range port that is available at the time.

Comment: I meant can't I specify what port to use instead ?

Comment: For the client to send FROM? No. Why would you want to? It's the port the server sends FROM and the client sends TO that is important.

Comment: I understand the range thing, but what is the purpose of this port ? what can I do with it ? I only want to use one certain port...

Comment: You don't do anything with it. You're not "using" it in the sense you normally think of using a port. Just ignore it entirely and focus on the server's port; it's the only one that matters. There are always ports like this for every client-server connection, but you don't care about them.

Comment: You can change the port if you want to, but in 99.9% of the cases there is no point in it.

Comment: Contrary to what @agf says, you can actually "use" this port to receive replies to the broadcast. This can be incredibly useful!! (e.g. a client can broadcast to a specific port to say "who's here?" then all listeners to the broadcast can reply just to the client by sending to the addr in the recvfrom.)

Comment: @dlm Certainly, but in his use case, knowing the port being sent on isn't important because the socket is already open so he can just keep using it.

Answer (score 1):

It definitely is the port. You can verify it on the sender side with `print sock.getsockname()`.

You can as well set it deliberately with e. g. `sock.bind(('', 54312))` before the `sock.sendto()` line.

This could be useful in context where software checks the port range of the sender: Ports 0..1023 are privileged ports - under many OSes only `root` is allowed to bind to these ports.

However, in the very most cases there is no point in changing it, so it mostly is better to leave it set the way it is.

This port has the meaning to be the 4th element of the tuple identifying a connection or counterpart of a connection. The tuple is (source_ip, source_port, destination_ip, destination_port).