# What is this address that I'm getting from recvfrom?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I am trying to learn about network communications and sockets. Here is some code that I wrote:

Client code:

```
from socket import *

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind('127.0.0.1', 3000)
data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
print "Received data '" + data + "' from address:", addr
```

Server code:

```
from socket import *
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.sendto("HELLO WORLD", ('127.0.0.1', 3000))
sock.close()
```

The client prints out: `Received data 'HELLO WORLD!' from address: ('127.0.0.1', 60788)`
To my understanding, the second member of the tuple is supposed to be the port. Furthermore, if I send several messages the number increase by 1 every time. Why is it not 3000?

As a side-note, are the htons and htonl functions necessary with the python API?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the second part of the address returned by recvfrom?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999207/what-is-the-second-part-of-the-address-returned-by-recvfrom)

Comment: It's the from-address. You know your own address, recvfrom() doesn't give you that again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: The scripts that you've written here would typically be regarded as a server and client, respectively, not client and server. This is because the server (the first script) is binding to a known port and waiting for a connection, while the client (the second script) is connecting to it from a random port and sending data.

To answer your questions directly:

- Since you aren't binding the client to any specific port, it's choosing a new epheremal port for each socket, and those are being used sequentially. If the server were to send a packet back to that same host and port, it would be received by the client.
- The `htons` and `htonl` functions are not generally necessary in Python. The `socket` module takes care of endian-swapping addresses and port numbers for you.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the difference between client and server.

Answer (score 1):

The port you are seeing is the port the data was sent *from*, not the port the data was sent *to*. When you don't specify the source port, and your "server" doesn't, the system assigns the socket a source port.